# select many to many whith parameter

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm a beginer with doctrine and I can't figure out how to make a query.

I'm with Symfony2 and I have two entities: `Equipment` and `Domain`.
They are related by a bi-directionnal ManyToMany.

In my `DomainRepository` I want to have the related `Domains` for an `Equipment`.

I've tried this but it doesn't return anything:

```php
public function getDomainsRelatedToEquipment($id)
{   
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb->addSelect('e');
    $qb->leftJoin('d.equipements','e');
    $qb->where('e.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

Could you help me making a builder that give me every `Domain` containing the `Equipment` with id `$id`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Expr::in()`.

```php
/**
 * @param int $id Equipment ID
 * @return array
 */
public function getDomainsRelatedToEquipment($id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('e.domains', array('?1'));

    $q = $qb->getQuery();
    $q->setParameter(1, $id);

    return $q->execute();
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I haven't test my code!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried but it doesn't work.
i've made an action for testing :

```
public function testAction() {
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->getRepository('myBundle:Equipement')->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('e.domaines', array('?1')));
    $q = $qb->getQuery();
    $q->setParameter(1, 1);

    var_dump($q->getArrayResult());

}
```

But i've got a semantical error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 61 near 'domaines IN(': Error: Invalid PathExpression.     
StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

My class Equipement have a field domaines.

```
class Equipement
{
[...]

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Domaine", inversedBy="equipements")
 */
private $domaines;
```

I've avoided the problem by building an array like this :

```
    $domaines = array();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $equipement = $em->getRepository('iMDEODISAASBundle:Equipement')->find($equipementId);
    $repoDomaine = $em->getRepository('iMDEODISAASBundle:Domaine');
    $idx = 0;
    foreach ($equipement->getDomaines() as $domaine) {
        $d= $repoDomaine->get($domaine->getId());
        $domaines[$idx]=$d[0];
        $idx++;
    }
    return $domaines;
```

But i guess this is not the best way for doing this.